# How to return script IDs not in policies

Tags: mysql

I need to identify a list of scripts not in use via our mySQL database. 
Active policies have a "created_by" value of "JSS" in the "policies" table. All Scripts are listed in the "scripts" table. Scripts used in all policies are listed in the "policy_scripts" table. "scrips.script_id" and "policy_scripts.script_id" are the same.

table: `policies`
column: `policy_id`
column: `created_by`

table: `scripts`
column:`script_id`
column: `file_name`

table: `policy_scripts`
column: `script_id`
column: `policy_id`

My Two attempts were:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    s.file_name
FROM
    policy_scripts AS ps
        LEFT JOIN
    scripts AS s ON ps.script_id = s.script_id
WHERE
    ps.script_id != ANY (SELECT 
            script_id
        FROM
            scripts)
ORDER BY s.file_name;
```

and

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT script_id)
FROM
    policy_scripts
WHERE
    script_id != ANY (SELECT 
            script_id
        FROM
            scripts);
```

however I don't think this is working as intended... It also does not take into account active policies. I'm not sure how to add that in.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Learn to use LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
select script_id 
from scripts s
    left outer join policy_scripts ps on ps.script_id = s.script_id
where ps.policy_id is NULL;
```